# call to resx with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resx

I've resx file for translation in my project and I want to replace all the text 
that will become from this file,when I use text without parameters like following its working

```
objRes.ErrorMsg = Group.err_message_duplicate;//This replace the entire string
```

The problem is that I want to replace the following strings

```
 objRes.ErrorMsg = "user " + username + " doesn't exist in" + table;
```

**For it I create in the resx file the following entry**

```
User  {0} doesn't exist in {1}
```

How should I use the resx with parameters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
objRes.ErrorMsg = string.Format("User {0} doesn't exist in {1}", username, table);
```

If coming from the variable `Group.err_message_duplicate`, use this:

```
objRes.ErrorMsg = string.Format(Group.err_message_duplicate, username, table);
```

Comment: Regex isn't mentioned in the question, it's "resx" - as in, a string in a resource file :)

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney: Oh, I see the typo, I read it as regx > regex instead of resx. Lol :)

Comment: The question is about localizing with resx. This does not answer it at all!

Comment: @under you are wrong. The OP already has a resource file and obtained a string from it. They just need to format it. This answer provides an answer to that.

Comment: Updated the question to remove the regx typo.

Also, I would recommend naming your resx key err_message_duplicate_format to make it clearer the value is only the format not the final output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Format`...

```
objRes.ErrorMsg = string.Format(Group.err_message_duplicate, username, table);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a regex. Looks like you want a simple string format like:

```
objRes.ErrorMsg = string.Format(Resources.MyMessage, username, table);
```