# Does .Net provide any functionality for performing named parameter substitution in template strings?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

We can have parameters in resource-strings quite easily ([call to resx with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244264/call-to-resx-with-parameters)) but this uses the typical `String.Format` where parameters are passed in the order used in a string like `"Name is {0}, age is {1}"`.

My scenario is a method like the following (pseudo), which looks for named template parameters in the resource string and replaces them with specified values:

```
string PerformSubstitution(string templateText,Dictionary<string,string> parameterNamesAndValues)
{
 foreach(var p in parameterNamesAndValues)
 {
   var paramName = p.Key;
   var paramValue = p.Value;
   templateText = SubstituteParameter(templateText,paramName,paramValue);
 }
 return templateText; //substitutions have been made for any parameters found
}
```

Usage might be along the lines of:

```
var myParams = new Dictionary<string,string>{ {"name","Dave"}, {"age","34"}};
var str = PerformSubstitution("User <name> is <age> years old",myParams);
```

Typically the template string would actually be stored as a localised resource in multiple languages so we'd actually use it like:

```
var str = PerformSubstitution(Strings.UserAgeDesc,myParams);
```

Now obviously I *can* write `SubstituteParameter` in various ways but before I jump into string replacement code and deciding on a substitution string syntax used throughout the project, does .Net provide anything already that we can just use, which already handles all the nasty special cases one might encounter?

Comment: Does string interpolation work for your use case? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: As a side note: you could use Liquid templates: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/ There are various implementations for .NET, e.g.: https://github.com/sebastienros/fluid